# Adding constant values at the begining of a dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark

I am trying to read a CSV file from HDFS location and to that 3 columns batchid,load timestamp and a delete indicator needs to be added at the beginning. I am using spark 2.3.2 and python 2.7.5. Sample values for 3 columns to be added is given below.

- batchid- YYYYMMdd (int)
- Load timestamp - current timestamp (timestamp)
- delete indicator - blank (string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little bit obscure. You can do something in this flavor. First, create your timestamp using `python` functionalities :

```py
import time
import datetime

timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Then, assuming you use the `DataFrame API`, you plug that into your column :

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

df = (df
   .withColumn('time',
               psf.unix_timestamp(
                   psf.lit(timestamp),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
                   ).cast("timestamp")
               )
   .withColumn('batchid', psf.date_format('time', 'yyyyMMdd/yyy'))
   .withColumn('delete', psf.lit(''))
```

To reorder your columns:

```py
df = df.select(*["time","batchid","delete"] + [k for k in colnames if k not in ["time","batchid","delete"]])
```

Comment: How to add this at the begining of DF?